# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error with CASE

Tags: sql, case

Table structure:

```
Customer
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(100) null
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID, 
  (SELECT CASE WHEN (Name IS NULL AND Name <> '')
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
   FROM Customer) AS IsNameNullOrWhitespace
```

This gives me 'Subquery returned more than 1 value This is ..'. Why is this?

Comment: ... because the subquery returned more than 1 value.

Comment: The message is very suggestive. Your second `SELECT` returns more than 1 value

Comment: If you mean "Why > 1 row returned?", that is dependent on your data, which you declined to share. If you mean "Why is > 1 row not allowed?", that is because a subquery that returns > 1 row is a RELATION, which must be JOINED to the rest of the query; it cannot be used as a scalar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you do not need a subquery- you can embed the `case` into the top-level `select`, like this:

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( name IS NULL 
                AND name <> '' ) THEN Cast(1 AS BIT) 
         ELSE Cast(0 AS BIT) 
       END AS IsNameNullOrWhitespace 
FROM   customer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, 
Case When IsNull(Name,'') ='' Then CAST(1 AS BIT) Else CAST(0 AS BIT) End  
IsNameNullOrWhitespace
FROM Customer
```

You need above query.